# Firebase real-time database is running 3 hours in past and not allowing to edit data manually

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We have stopped all writes to the firebase real-time database specific node . Still node data is getting updated every 2-3 seconds. Time shown is 3 hours back.
We are not even able to add any key-value inside this node.

Comment: Have you tried changing the timezone?

Comment: We have been using same thing from last 7 months, everything was working as expected.This time it is behaving differently.